# What makes NgModelController a controller?

Tags: angularjs

It says [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController) that, 'NgModelController provides API for the ng-model directive.'

So why isn't it called NgModelDirective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A directive can (but doesn't have to) have a controller.

`NgModelController` is literally the controller that is used for the ngModel directive. I imagine that is why it is named accordingly.

You can see where [ngModel is defined here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.1.5/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1112) and [the controller is here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.1.5/src/ng/directive/input.js#L902)

```
var ngModelDirective = function() {
  return {
    require: ['ngModel', '^?form'],
    controller: NgModelController
    // *snip*
}
```

Comment: Seems strange to me that a directive would need a controller when it has set-up methods such as 'link'.

Comment: link is fine when you want to hook up to native events and what not, but sometimes a directive is more complex than that. For instance it may have a template that has bindings and requires scope properties to be setup. Having a controller + template makes all these things much cleaner.

Comment: So if you add ng-controller="ctrl1" to a <ng- form /> tag, doesn't that mean the element gets two controllers?

Comment: You can have nested controllers in angular so I think they just nest. From playing around with an example it looks like the directive becomes the parent and the controller is nested within it. You can play with it here http://plnkr.co/edit/ii17zn?p=preview

Comment: Why would a directive have a controller? A directive is for manipulating the DOM whereas no such code is supposed to appear in a controller.

Comment: From official docs "Directives are a way to teach HTML new tricks" directives aren't about DOM manipulation, they just happen to be the place where it is considered OK to happen.